# flask+nginx+gunicorn with docker run error

Tags: docker, flask

I use flask+nginx+gunicorn in docker,but when I goto http://127.0.0.1 on my computer. It according to Welcome to nginx! Not my flask_app Index page.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

flask_nginx.conf

```
server {
   listen  80;
   server_name 120.0.0.1;

   location  /  {
      proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8001;
   }
  }
```

supervisor.conf

```
[program:nginx-app]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/nginx_stdout.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/nginx_error.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB

[program:app-gunicorn]
command = /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8001 app:app
directory = /app
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn_out.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/gunicorn_error.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 10MB
```

dockerfile

```
## Dockerfile that generates an instance of www.longjj.com
FROM ubuntu:16.04

LABEL maintainer="BlackRun"
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8


RUN  sed -i s@/archive.ubuntu.com/@/mirrors.aliyun.com/@g /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& sed -i s@/security.ubuntu.com/@/mirrors.aliyun.com/@g /etc/apt/sources.list \
&& apt-get clean \
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev nginx supervisor\
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ADD pip.conf /etc/pip.conf
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip


COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt \
&& ln -s /app/flask.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d \
&& sed -i 's/nodaemon=false/nodaemon=true/g' /etc/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

and docker container run is

```
docker container run --name flask_shili -d -p 80:80 flask
```

Please help me,Thanks!

Comment: How did you run the docker container & what does container logs say? Add Dockerfile as well.

Comment: I add Dockerfile and docker run container command,thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate the scenario, removing the nginx default config file worked for me. Probably because the default `server_name` was matching too & causing a conflict. Change your Dockerfile section -

```
........
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt \
&& ln -s /app/flask.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d \
&& rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default \
&& sed -i 's/nodaemon=false/nodaemon=true/g' /etc/supervisord.conf
......
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much!